# Login loop after removing old kernels

Tags: 14.04, kernel, login

I used [the last command of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu/254585#254585) to remove (many) old images and kernels. My current kernel is 3.16.0-76.

After that I am stuck in a login loop.

I already tried/checked the following things but none of them helped:

- restore lightdm
- X.authority is correct
- reinstall compiz
- reinstall current kernel
- reinstall xOrg
- use a new user

What could be the problem here? With `startx` I am able to start the x-server, but that is not really a solution.

Comment: try: sudo apt-get -f install, once I had a similar problem and it solved the login loop

Comment: unfortunately that didnt do anything. I tried with sudo apt-get autoclean as well, did not help.

Comment: What do you call "login loop"? You can access lightdm login screen but not your unity session?

Comment: Yes, I come to the point where I can enter my password, after that I come there again and unity is not loaded.